# Is one allowed to drink alcohol on regular weekdays?

Tags: halacha, health-safety-shmira, liquor-beer, chol-weekday

Is it permissible to drink alcohol in any circumstance other than Holidays and Shabbat? Please cite sources.

[CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).

Comment: מצוה גדולה להיות בשמחה תמיד?

Comment: על המחיה (with a Kammatz)?

Comment: @SethJ שמחה גדולה להיות במצווה תמיד and we know a שיכור is patur from mitzvot.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10609/759

Comment: Why would one think otherwise?

Comment: @yitznewton See the linked question about marijuana. Alcohol is a drug too, and perhaps some parallel concerns may apply. They also may not apply, but that's why we have this question.

Comment: @SethJ the rebbe didn't approve of drinking outside of Shabbos and Yom Tov, and even then only a little.

Comment: @yoel Can you clarify which rebbe?

Comment: @DoubleAA sorry, the one being quoted - Rebbe Nachman of Breslev zy'a

Comment: Why would we expect that there is a source to explicitly permits us to do something that isn't forbidden?

Comment: @Yirmeyahu the Rambam prohibits it.

Comment: @Hacham Gabriel, Where?

Comment: @Yirmeyahu I hear your concern.

Comment: וְטֽוֹב־לֵ֝֗ב מִשְׁתֶּ֥ה תָמִֽיד׃

Answer (score 16):

Rambam Hilchos De'os [5:3](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/1205n.htm#5)

> ג. כשהחכם שותה יין אינו שותה אלא כדי לשרות אכילה שבמעיו וכל המשתכר הרי זה חוטא ומגונה ומפסיד חכמתו ואם נשתכר בפני עמי הארץ הרי זה חילל את השם ואסור לשתות יין בצהרים ואפילו מעט אלא אם היה בכלל האכילה שהשתיה שהיא בכלל האכילה אינה משכרת ואין נזהרין אלא מיין שלאחר המזון.‏

My loose translation:

> A Chacham only drinks wine only to digest [soften] food in his stomach. Anyone who gets drunk is a sinner, shameful and loses his wisdom and if one gets drunk in front of amei ha'aretz it is a chillul Hashem. It is forbidden to drink even a little bit of wine in the afternoon unless it is with food, for wine during a meal does not intoxicate, but after the meal is when it should be avoided.

Comment: This seems like a "medical recommendation" than a Halacha. Looking for maybe an Aharon's Pesak.

Comment: @HachamGabriel If it were a medical recommendation, it wouldn't say it applies only to a chacham.

Comment: @ba a _Chakham_ , in [De'ot 1:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/1201n.htm#9)[4], is defined as "man whose traits are intermediate and equally balanced"( translation from [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/910340/jewish/Chapter-One.htm)). In 1:11[5] it says that "[walking] in these intermediate paths" is a _Mitzvat Aseh_ of _le-hidamot bi-Drakhav_ ( "To emulate His ways"). So yes, it is a _Halakhah_ , but no, it doesn't apply only to a "chacham".

Comment: This is a nice answer to the question, because Rambam's statement clearly presumes that it is OK to drink wine with normal meals.

Answer (score 2):

See Sefer Marphe Habosem(end of the Sefer) who writes that it's healthy to drink a little wine daily.

Comment: who is the Author?

Comment: Rabbi Shauli. It's based on the Rambam and the like.