# Choosing a "Posek"

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

How does one go about choosing his own personal *Posek*(halachic authority) Sources , if available , are appreciated.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/36302/5083