# Are there high level poskim who are easily accessible?

Tags: halacha, rabbis, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

I often have Halachic questions that upon approaching local Orthodox rabbonim, I don't feel comfortable with their psak. I know enough to know that they don't have a complete grasp of halacha but I don't know enough to deal with the questions on my own. I have no problem accepting the psak and moving on but I really wish I could approach someone approaching the level of Rav Moshe Feinstein who had everything at his fingertips. Are there any leading poskim (ones who have a complete mastery of all areas of halacha) who are easily accessible for the regular guy on the street?

Comment: Give me an example of the question here in the comments.

Comment: Dinonline is a great resource with real talmidei chachamim who answer questions in a timley manner,I believe you can call as well

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8303/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34566/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69909/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47398/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65203/759 probably a dupe in there

Comment: @aron. Case specific questions as far as cheating/stealing from government. Case specific questions with regard to an abortion. Case specific questions as far as forcing a get.

Comment: I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but most major frum communities have batei din with dayanim who are available for shailos from the public pretty much around the clock. The dayanim tend to be the best learned people in the community, and in some communities, that is saying quite a bit.

Comment: I wouldn't aim for the leading poskim of the generation. There is more of a middle road - very learned, great talmidei chachamim and poskim, who know far more than your local Orthodox rabbi (I would guess, without knowing where you live) who are very accessible. Find someone who lives reasonably locally and inquire when you can speak to him. If he doesn't know, he will himself pass it on to the "greatest poskim".

Comment: Yiftach Bedoro Keshmuel Bedoro.

Comment: This is a touchy situation, and I'm not referring to the politics involved with, esp. congregational rabbis. Sometimes, this interferes with their ability to issue an acceptable answer to your situation. The problem is that you're not supposed to go rabbi shopping. However, if you knew a source that clearly disproved what the rabbi said, you could respectfully challenge him. Your first sentence sounds like you already have a bias prior to your asking the question. If that's the case, don't ask that person in the first place. Please explain WHY you're  "uncomfortable".

Comment: I've been able to contact Rabbi David Feinstein relatively easily, during the 2 or 3 times that I needed him. Rav Moshe Tendler was also relatively easily accessible. Years ago, I needed his opinion on a medical question. Having said this, I think you should edit your question to give us a sense of why you think you would be more accepting of their opinion vs. a local rav. There's some info that I think is missing, here.

Comment: @Dan. Pretty much like I said in the question. When I read a teshuva or from someone like Rav Moshe ztl, I feel like he had everything at his fingertips. Local Rabbonim, although they're great, they're accessible, they're helpful etc but when I ask a question that I happen to know alot about, I realize that they're very far away from even being close to the level of Rav Moshe. And sometimes when you're asking a question that you really care about, you want the best out there.

Comment: @MarkA. What do you think would happen if everyone only asked their questions of the top rabbi of the generation? Have you ever read Exodus 18? It's worth a read. The system is around for a reason, and is the traditional Jewish practice. Good local rabbis know their limitations, and will direct you upward when necessary.

Comment: " And sometimes when you're asking a question that you really care about, you want the best out there". The best answer may not necessarily be the  best for your specific needs. Within almost any halacha, there are must / inflexible rules and there are numerous nuances and exceptions to accomodate special circumstances. Not every rav can be a specialist in everything. Even Gedolim frequently had to ask other gedolim for advice. See end of @DoubleAA's last comment. It's precise.

Comment: @SAH I haven't had to use a *bet din* other than to ask a "historical" question related to my parents' unique *ketubah* (it was written for 2 deaf people and involved the *bet din* to intervene. Fascinating halacha!) As I understand, the bet din's function is involved mainly in conversions and *gittin* as well as arbitration of civil disputes. Sometimes, as in the above, they are involve in *ketubot*. But, I don't think their function is in *sho'el umeishiv* - answering halachic questions.

Comment: @danf in my community, they pasken on all types of stuff including really small. That is one reason most people give them 180 a year in mas hakohol

Answer (score 3):

Although there is no substitute for a personal Rav who understands one's own specific situation, if someone is in a difficult situation then I have found http://dinonline.org/ to be a strong group of talmidei chachamim and dayanim who can answer questions over email or the phone. Within just a couple days, they can relay your question to the gedolei haposkim in Eretz Yisrael for guidance too.

Answer (score 0):

Rav Shlomo Miller shlita, a posek in Canada and one of the contemporary gedolei hador
Web site: "frumtoronto" (send the questions to his assistant and he will get back to you in about a week or so)

There are other Web sites that answer questions, but Rav Miller is the only one I know of where you can get an answer from a gadol.

You can also go to various rabbis in person.