# Does Birkas Hamazon eliminate the need for bracha acharona on foods eaten before?

Tags: halacha, blessing, bentching, kavana-intent

Someone ate something which, in and of itself, requires a bracha achrona (e.g. Al Hamichya or Borei Nefashos) and carelessly moved on to eating bread before reciting said bracha achrona. Should one say the bracha achrona for the first food in addition to birkas hamazon or would birkas hamazon alone (b'dieved) satisfy this requirement?

Also, would I be required in such cases while reciting birkas hamazon to have kavanah about the food I had both during *and* before the meal?

Related situation: [Does birkat hamazon cover dessert (and other items requiring a separate bracha rishona during the meal)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77080/2091)

Comment: Motivation: it just happened to me. (Yeah, it was a hard meal.)

Comment: I asked this question to my Rav and he said as soon as you realized you didn't say the bracha acharona, even in the middle of a hamotzi meal, go ahead and say the bracha achrona. He didn't address what happens if you don't remember that you forgot the bracha until the end of the hamotzi meal, though. (He noted that wine at kiddush is the only example of a bracha said before hamotzi that is taken care of by birkas hamazon.)

Comment: Thanks! Great job pointing out kiddush, by the way. I knew that was what I had in mind.

Comment: @Kordovero Actually, your last sentence seems to imply that both blessings would need to be said after the meal in my case. Still, I'm hesitant to say two in a row like that, where one is Birkat Hamazon...

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean...hopefully someone can find an answer.

Comment: Is this a scenario where you knew from the start that you were going to eat a meal? Also, did you eat the snack as an appetizer?

Comment: @Fred I knew I was going to keep eating, but didn't know I was going to have bread until the last minute. (My minchag is only to make hamotzi on bread per se.)

Comment: @SAH Ok, these are complicated *halachos* where minor details can be significant, and there are differences of opinion, so ultimately CYLOR is in order. Different types of *m'zonos* foods could have different *halachos*, but *Birkas HaMazon* probably covers all *m'zonos* eaten beforehand at least *b'diavad* (especially if one intended that the *bentching* apply to it). I'm not entirely sure of the impact of the fact that you planned on continuing to eat (those same foods?), though not in the context of a meal, but assuming that it counts as not having planned to eat more of it during a meal...

Comment: @SAH ...then fruit eaten beforehand (or other foods that would require a blessing if eaten during a meal) would require a *borei n'fashos* even during the meal (there may be different opinions regarding whether you would even have to recite *borei n'fashos* after *bentching* if you forgot to do so beforehand). Dates are an exception; *bentching* covers them since they are a substantial food. For other non-*m'zonos* snacks, *borei n'fashos* would be required (according to most poskim) even if you intended to continue eating them during a meal. (Note: Wine and drinks have different *halachos*).

Comment: @SAH Some sources: *Mishna B'rura* [176:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%95) (as well as *Bei'ur Halacha* and *Sha'ar HaTziyun*, and sources cited ad loc.; see also *M"B* on [OC 208:17](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%97));  [*Igros Moshe* OC III 33](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&pgnum=323); *V'zos HaBracha* ch. 9.

Comment: @Fred Thank you so much for this information. If you posted it at as an answer, I'd definitely upvote. BTW, do you know about shehakol?

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but it bears mentioning: When the "related situation" described at the end of my question occurred last Shabbos, I was told by my rabbi that we didn't need to make borei n'fashos after bentching. Wasn't told why, though.

Comment: @SAH I attempted to make your question more succinct/fluid in preparation to answer it. Please let me know if I altered your intent in doing so.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77080/2091

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yalqut Yosef - Qizur Shulhan 'Arukh ([Orah Hayim 177:6](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_13.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%96B-B%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AAB%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9DB%D7%94%D7%91%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9DB%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9AB%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%95)) states (my translation):

> יש הנוהגים בשבת ויום טוב, לברך על בשר ודגים, ביצים ומיני תבשיל, או פירות, קודם נטילת ידים וברכת המוציא, כדי להשלים מאה ברכות בשבת. ויש להם על מה שיסמוכו. ואין חילוק בזה בין אנשים לנשים. [אך אחר שהתחיל בסעודה אין לברך על בשר דגים ומיני תבשיל]. וכיון שאוכלים קודם הסעודה, יזהרו שלא יאכלו כזית, כדי שלא יכנסו בספק ברכה אחרונה. ואם אכלו מהם כזית קודם הסעודה, [אחר הקידוש], לא יברכו ברכה אחרונה, שספק ברכות להקל. וכן אם אכל עוגה קודם הסעודה שיעור כזית, אינו מברך ברכה אחרונה, דשמא ברכת המזון פוטרתו.
>
> Some have the custom on Shabbat and Yom Tov to recite blessings on meat, fish, eggs, [Lee: other] types of dishes, or fruit before Nettilat Yadayim and Birkat HaMozi in order to recite one hundred blessings on Shabbat [Lee: and Yom Tov]. And they have upon what to rely. And there is no difference [Lee: in this ruling] between men and women. [But, after starting the *se'udah*, one must not recite blessings on fish and other types of dishes].
>
> And, since they are eating before the *se'udah*, **they must be careful not to eat a "*kezayit*"** so as not to place themselves in a *safeq Berakhah Aharonah* [Lee: i.e. a situation in which it's unclear if they should recite a *Berakhah Aharonah* or not]. And, **if they nevertheless ate a *kezayit* before the *se'udah* [after the *Qiddush*], they should not recite a *Berakhah Aharonah*** since *safeq berakhot lehaqel* [Lee: i.e. we opt to not recite blessings other than *Birkat HaMazon* if there is uncertainty if they are required or not].
>
> **If one ate a *kezayit* of cake before the *se'udah***, it is similarly true that **one should not recite a *Berakhah Aharonah*** since *Birkat HaMazon* may apply to the cake eaten.

I was recently told, though **I have not yet researched this "inside"**, that **the Mishnah Berurah rules that one should recite a *Berakhah Aharonah*** in the cases outlined above.

Yalqut Yosef does not directly address your question of *kawanah* (i.e. intent) in this clause. I assume *Birkat HaMazon* should be recited with the foods from before the meal in mind (since I am not aware of negative legal ramifications for doing so).

Comment: I believe Yalqut Yosef rules this way since the *Berakhah Aharonah* is subject to a *mahloqet haposseqim*. Since, according to Yalqut Yosef, all blessings (other than *Birkat HaMazon*) are Rabbinic in nature, and since this *Berakhah Aharonah* is subject to a *safeq*, we apply the general principle of *safeq berakhot lehaqel* - i.e. we would rather passively not fulfill a Rabbinic decree than actively break a negative Biblical commandment (of reciting HaShem's name in vain).

Comment: So you are saying that the  Shulchan Aruch rules one way and the Mishnah Berurah another way? I assume we follow the S"A?

Comment: Also, I thought I learned that saying an unnecessary bracha does not constitute a Biblical transgression. (maybe it was actually just that it's not a violation of the Third Commandment?)

Comment: According to Yalqut Yosef ([Orah Hayim 215:9](http://ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_16.html#סימןBרטוB-BענייתBאמןBאחרBהברכות-ט)) - in the name of Shulhan \`Arukh, "Hage'onim", and RaMBa"M - reciting an unnecessary blessing is a Biblical prohibition. As to which de\`ah to follow, please [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17293/is-one-allowed-to-drink-alcohol-on-regular-weekdays).