# Does birkat hamazon cover dessert (and other items requiring a separate bracha rishona during the meal)?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, bentching, meal-seudah

During a bread-based meal, but before *bentching* (i.e. reciting *birkat hamazon*), I eat something (e.g. fruit, dessert, etc.) that traditionally requires a separate *bracha rishona*.

Must I say a separate *bracha acharona* for that item (either before or after *birkat hamazon*)? Or is it covered by the *birkat hamazon* on the meal of which it was not a part?

Comment: Since you've made this a separate question, you might want to remove the added paragraph in [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/54048/does-birkas-hamazon-eliminate-the-need-for-bracha-acharona-on-foods-eaten-before?rq=1) related question of yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are eaten during the meal, **you need only Bracha Rishona**.

After the meal, is also generally considered as during the meal until you say birkat Hamazon.

In some special cases described in Beur Halacha bellow, there is a Machloket for the kind of food you described (fruit, dessert). This last topic is explained briefly below.

See  Berachot 41b:

> אמר רב פפא הלכתא: ‏
>
> 1. דברים הבאים מחמת הסעודה בתוך הסעודה אין טעונים ברכה לא לפניהם ולא לאחריהם
> 2. ושלא מחמת הסעודה בתוך הסעודה טעונים ברכה לפניהם ואין טעונים ברכה לאחריהם
> 3. **לאחר הסעודה** טעונים ברכה בין לפניהם בין לאחריהם. ‏

Rashi:

> דברים הרגילים לבא לאחר סעודה - כגון פירות אפי' הביאן בתוך הסעודה שלא מחמת לפתן:‏
>
> We found in Gemara that foods which are generally not a part of the meal  and are eaten after the meal (there is discussion if the two conditions are necessary), need blessing before and after (not included in motsi or Birkat Hamazon).

Se SA OC [177, 2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x992)

> ודברים הבאים לאחר סעודה קודם ברכת המזון שהיה מנהג בימי חכמי הגמרא שבסוף הסעודה היו מושכים ידיהם מן הפת ומסירים אותו וקובעים עצמם לאכול פירות ולשתות כל מה שמביאים אז לפניהם בין דברים הבאים מחמת הסעודה בין דברים הבאים שלא מחמת הסעודה טעונים ברכה **בין לפניהם בין לאחריהם** דהמוציא וברכת המזון אין פוטרין אלא מה שנאכל תוך עיקר הסעודה **ודין זה האחרון אינו מצוי בינינו לפי שאין אנו רגילין למשוך ידינו מן הפת עד ברכת המזון.**‏
>
> Shulchan Aruch said that this last rule apply in situation which have no equivalent in our standard custom of eating. So the birkat Hamazon is efficient for any food eaten before Birkat Hamazon.

See Magen Avraham sk 7:

> ול"נ שהטעם כמ"ש תר"י וז"ל דוקא בימיהם שהיו נוהגין לעקור השלחנות קודם ב"ה וע"כ נראה כסעודה אחרת אבל אנו שאין מסלקין השלחן אף על פי שסיימו מלאכול כל זמן שלא ברכו כתוך הסעודה דיינין ליה:‏
>
> Magen Avraham report discussions about a such situation today, in rare cases, mentioning some Acharonim (Levush, Bach). He concludes, according to talmide Rabeynu Yona, that the main difference between our time and the time of Gemara is that in time of Gemara, they were moving entirely the table and eating after removing the table is as a separate meals. So since we don't remove the table, the rule doesn't apply nowadays.

See Beur Halacha:

> ואם נטל הכוס לברך דהוא היסח הדעת גמור וכמבואר בסימן קע"ט לכאורה אף בזמנינו אין לך סילוק סעודה יותר מזה ואם אכל אח"כ איזה דבר יש לו לברך תחלה וסוף ולא נפטר בבהמ"ז ומתחלה בודאי יש לו לברך אף על דברים שנפטרים בתוך הסעודה מן הברכה לגמרי [דגם לפת עצמו צריך ברכה לרוב הפוסקים אחר שנטל הכוס לברך כמבואר בסימן קע"ט] אלא דגם לבסוף יהיה צריך ברכה אז וכ"כ הגר"ז בפשיטות וכ"מ מהמגן אברהם סימן ר"ח סקכ"ד אכן המאמר מרדכי שם בסקל"ה חולק ע"ז עי"ש. ובדברים הבאים מחמת הסעודה נראה ודאי דיש לסמוך על דעתו שלא לברך דבלא"ה יש ראשונים דסברי דהגמרא לא קאי על דברים הבאים מחמת סעודה וכנ"ל:.‏
>
> The beur Halacha, describes in name of the Baal Hatanya in name of the Magen Avraham in an other siman, that **when they already served the Birkat Hamazon cup**, even nowadays, if someone eats something, he needs to bless before and after it. But Maamar Mordechay disagrees. If someone eat a food which is not usually  a part of the meal, at this time, Machloket, Beur Halacha says he cannot decide what is the Halacha. But if the food is usually eaten into the meal, he holds as the Maamar Mordechay.

Answer (score 1):

Qizur Shulhan 'Arukh - Yalqut Yosef ([Orah Hayim 177:1](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_13.html#HtmpReportNum0005_L2)) writes (my translation):

> כל מיני פירות, אם אוכל אותם בלי פת, טעונים ברכה לפניהם, שברכת המוציא אינה פוטרתם, שאינם מעיקר הסעודה. אבל אינם טעונים ברכה לאחריהם, שכיון שבאו בתוך הסעודה, ברכת המזון פוטרתם
>
> All types of fruit, when eaten without bread, require a *Berakhah Rishonah* since *Birkat HaMotzi* doesn't account for them (since they are not essential to the meal). But, they do not require a *Berakhah Aharonah* since *Birkat HaMazon* accounts for them (since they were eaten during the meal).