# Are non-Lubavitch Tanya editions listed?

Tags: jewish-books, chabad, tanya

Every edition I've seen of [*Tanya*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likkutei_Amarim) includes a list, in chronological order, of every edition of *Tanya* ever printed, including bibliographic information. I assume some central Lubavitch office maintains the list. Now, *Tanya* is studied also by non-Lubavitch (non-*Chabad*) *chasidim* (and perhaps other Jews), and I assume that there have been editions of it published by such — and even if not, there certainly can be in the future. Are those editions listed also, as the central Lubavitch office hears of them?

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28251

Comment: Look at the last paragraph here: http://www.shturem.org/index.php?section=news&id=65361 ... Does Kehos own a copyright to the Tanya??

Comment: @AdamMosheh It may simply be a request to his chassidim, rather than anything to do with copyrights.

Comment: @fred IIRC, the Previous Rebbe said that Sifrei Chassidus belong to the Rabbeim, and therefore they belong to Kehos.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, Do other chassidusim hold like that? How does that mesh with copyright line (dina demalchusa) in most jurisdictions?

Comment: Potentially related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7915/are-there-other-extant-chabad-groups-besides-chabad-lubavitch